# Не могу разобраться в API платежной системы

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, rest, платежи

Всем привет. Есть платежная система QubiPay (документация) - https://docs.qubipay.io/first-steps.html.
Для работы с API я выбрал NodeJS, т.к. до этого работал с JS, но я вообще не понимаю что и как делать. Я совсем не силен в NodeJS, так что даже не знаю с чего здесь лучше начать.
Я подключил модули express и QubiPay, но тестовый режим так и не запускается. Крч, помогите пж. Хотя бы советом, с чего лучше начать для подключения этой платежки

Answer (score 0):

Что-бы отладить проблему запуска нужно хорошо разбираться в устройстве back-end части. Если этот навык есть, то просто пробуй разные способы, выводи логи и т.д. Если нет, тогда может быть стоит сначала пройти основы Node JS?